# Changing onclick() breaks cloning process

Tags: javascript, clone

I'm trying to create a button that clones an element 3 times, but when I try to change the clones `onclick()`, it doesn't clone the object.

```
var html = document.getElementById("kaart" + kaart_id).innerHTML;
kaart_id = kaart_id + 1;
var clone = document.createElement("div");
clone.innerHTML = html;
clone.id = "kaart" + kaart_id; 
clone.classList = "memory_kaart";
clone.onclick = kaart(kaart_id);
let tekst = clone.childNodes[1];
tekst.textContent = kaart_waarde;
tekst.id = "kaart" + kaart_id + "_tekst";
document.getElementById("memory_speelveld").appendChild(clone);
kaart_waarde = kaart_waarde + 1;
```

I'm trying to change the `onclick` to `kaart(kaart_id)` which is my other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function `kaart(kaart_id)` in your assignment which is why the event handler doesn't trigger. You need to pass a reference to the function instead, not call it.

Assign a reference to the function to the `onclick` handler by assigning the function declaration:

```
clone.onclick = function kaart(kaart_id) {
    // function statements
};
```

or by assign the function declaration to a variable first, then assigning the variable to the event handler:

```
let kaartFunc = function kaart(kaart_id) {
    // function statements
} 

clone.onclick = kaartFunc;
```

A rule of thumb is; if the function does not have the `function` keyword before its name and it has parentheses `()` after its name, you are calling the function, e.g `kaart(kaart_id)`.